# How to use zip with switchMap?

Tags: angular, rxjs

Im developing a angular 6 app and in my component I have this code:

```
 ngOnInit() {
   this.$subscription = this.route.params
     .pipe(map(param => param['id']))
     .pipe(switchMap(id => {
        this.id = id;
        console.log(this.id);
        return zip(
          this.remote1.getDetail(this.id),
          this.remote2.getDetail(this.id),
          this.remote3.getDetail(this.id)
    )
    })).subscribe(result => {
      console.log(result);
 }
```

When I run this code I get this error on console:

> ERROR TypeError: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
>       at subscribeTo (vendor.js:181613)
>       at subscribeToResult (vendor.js:181765)
>       at SwitchMap.....

I got the `console.log(this.id)` correctly, but not the `console.log(result)`.

All the methods inside the `zip` operator returns an `Observable`. What im missing here?

Comment: I think it should be `return zip(
          of(this.remote1.getDetail(this.id)),` etc..

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct `zip`? As you've used it, `zip` needs to be the static function imported from  `"rxjs"` and not the operator imported from `"rxjs/operators"`. In any case, I'd be expecting TypeScript to effect errors that ought to highlight exactly what's wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Zip accepts observables as inputs `signature: zip(observables: *): Observable`, so it should be:

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.$subscription = this.route.params
     .pipe(map(param => param['id']))
     .pipe(switchMap(id => {
        this.id = id;
        console.log(this.id);
        return zip(
          of(this.remote1.getDetail(this.id)),
          of(this.remote2.getDetail(this.id)),
          of(this.remote3.getDetail(this.id)),
    )
    })).subscribe(result => {
      console.log(result);
 }
```

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/zip.html